# Differentiability of function in (0,0)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is the function $$g(x,y)=x^{2}y^{2}\cos{{1}\over{x^{2}y^{2}}}$$ differentiable at $(0,0)$? I'm able to prove it's continuity in that point, but I'm stuck in proving if it's differentiable or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easy to see that the partial derivatives are $\partial_x g(0,0) = \partial_yg(0,0) = 0$. So it's differentiable if and only if $g(x,y)/|(x,y)| \rightarrow 0$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: If you can prove continuity then just take the derivative and show it's continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: It is not defined at $(0,0)$ and is therefore not differentiable there. Is there a definition of $g(0,0)$?